# Sending form data to email or autoresponder

Tags: html, asp.net, forms

I have a html form that sends users to register.aspx... here's what it begins with:

It takes input from user like username, password, emailaddress etc. and then creates an account for them.

I want to add one more functionality to the form... when use clicks 'Submit' they should as well receive an automated email from me saying that you're account has been created. The email should have a copy of the use details as well.

How is this possible?

I want to do this at the form level.

Comment: please include your code, also include the relevant ASP.NET tag

Comment: Here's the code: https://pastebin.com/bAXjUSBa

Comment: resources are plenty full, just google "asp.net sending emails", see this w3schools [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/webpages_email.asp)